# JavaScript Tooltip with run time data?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Writing a script to run on my school's registration website. I have modified the page so that the professor's names link to their respective pages just fine.

I now want to create a (I think the name is correct) tooltip on hover that displays 4 things like such. (I could make it 3, chili pepper isn't needed but fun).

[image: Example]

I'm totally new to learning all this. I obviously don't have direct access to page and I'm using the JS script for any modifications I've done.

Is this something I can do with vanilla JS? It's a chrome extension and the tooltip should be filled with the results from ajax requests. Very important that they be populated at runtime, not hard coded into the html/css. I think I can pop the CSS for the box into a file on the chrome extension and reference it from there.

Is this something I can do? Use the ajax results to fill the tooltip? An image that I can bottum/right justify too? Will it look horrible in the way I've sort of rough-drafted it? (Totally open to suggestions!)

Just looking to make sure that I can actually accomplish this and perhaps if someone has a direction they want to point me in, that'd be awesome. Any advice is greatly appreciated too.

Comment: You would actually only need css to do this. Juste put your "tooltip" content inside the name's wrapper and show it on hover in css with position absolute.

Comment: @Kiwad I'm a beginner, but I've learned a ton with this project but bear with me!. To clarify - So I can use JS to make the ajax calls and grab the data. Then put it around (wrapper) the somewhere in the name's wrapper and with CSS set it up to display on hover. The data will only be displayed on hover; given that it's somewhere else in the wrapper, not in the part being displayed on the page. Also, will this work for the image as well? And I can justify it to the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with vanilla JS without having to use css (you will need inline styling though), OR, you can mix css with this; It's your choice.

1. What you want to do is add onmouseover events on the names of the
   professors (or whatever you want to display the tooltip on), lets
   call this the 'tooltip target'.
2. In the onmouseover event handler/function, fire up any ajax requests you want and code up an html string of the tooltip box.
3. Find the position of the 'tooltip target'(See step 1) using getBoundingClientRect() and display the tooltip in that position using fixed
   or absolute positioning [by using appendChild()].

[EDIT]

Example:
OuterScope:

```
var currentTooltip = null;
```

MouseOver:

```
//Use ajax calls to fetch quality and difficulty
var root = document.createElement("div"); //This is the tooltip's root div
html = "<p> Overall Quality: " + quality + "</p>";
html += "<p> Difficulty: " + difficulty + "</p>";
root.innerHTML = html; //Add content to the tooltip
var bounds = tooltipTarget.getBoundingClientRect(); //Get bounds of the tooltip target
root.style.position = "absolute";
root.style.left = bounds.left + "px";
root.style.top = bounds.top + "px";
root.style.zIndex = "65535"; //Set max z-index so that it appears at the top
currentTooltip = root;
document.body.appendChild(root); //Displays the tooltip
```

MouseOut:

```
if(currentTooltip != null) document.body.removeChild(currentTooltip);
```

Comment: I think I might've lost you on #3 with getClientRect(), but I will research that. With #2 - Can I format the tooltip to allow the image to be justified just fine using html? And right now I loop through every 'tooltip target' and link to the prof's website through ajax calls. I can just add this tooltip modification inside that without making the same calls I assume. (Probably need to see code for this)

Comment: @Kevin yes, you can do anything you would normally do with HTML. And yes, if you already loop through them then adding this modification to existing code is the smarter option :D See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here's a quick way to achieve this. I know, I used jquery here but it's only to show you a way to do it. Afterward, you'll be able to regress it to vanilla js. I hope it helps you.

I made a function instead of your ajax call, the same function would be called on ajax success return.

```js
function ajaxIsOk($jqueryObj, response) {
  if (!$jqueryObj.hasClass('filled')) {
    $jqueryObj.append('<div class="tooltip"></div>');
    $jqueryObj.addClass('filled');
  }
  $jqueryObj.children('.tooltip').html(response);
}

$(".name").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).addClass('in');
  // do your ajax call here. I added this function call for the example
  ajaxIsOk($(this), 'HTML content : ' + Math.random());
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('in');
});
```

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
}

a.in .tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet <a href="#" class="name">Rutrum faucibus</a> dolor.</p>
```